# Vagrant: open mysql connection to host

Tags: mysql, vagrant, my.cnf

I'd like to use MySql Workbench to browse my database in Vagrant from host machine.

So far I just commented the line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in `my.cnf` and all was ok, but recently I connected to a new wi-fi and things seemed to change, I had to change guest ip address from `192.168.0.200` to `192.168.1.200` and I can't open mysql connection from host.

I tryed also to add `bind-address = 10.0.2.2` guessing (not sure) this was my host ip but still the same.

What do I need to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a static ip for your box like in this example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

      config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.6"
```

In Mysql Workbench create a new connection over SSH:

```
Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH

SSH Hostname: 10.0.0.6 (like above)

SSH Username: vagrant

SSH password: vagrant

MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1

MySQL Username: root

MySQL Password: root
```

**SSH Host Key identification:**

Instead of a password you can use the box specific Private Key. You can get the path by executing `vagrant ssh-config`.

Comment: This works great in mysql workbench. Unfortunately for me, the mysql excel plugin that i need to use while working on some CSV data does not have the option to connect over SSH.

Comment: Host key verification failed.